# как сделать этот Python скрипт рабочим в notepad++ (для открытого документа)

Tags: python, python-3.6, notepad++

Есть код (написан для Notepad++).... он берёт инфу из заявленного документа и возвращает результат в консоль (`Notepad++`)

Как сделать чтобы результат выводился в самом документе (в смысле редакторе а не консоли), а поверх того что было изначально. Помогите, пожалуйста... голову уже сломал…

```py
f = open("D:\\test.txt", 'r')
line = f.readline()
while line:
    A = line
    a1 = A[:-2]
    a2 = A[-3:-1]
    a2 = int(a2)
    print(str(a1)+str(a2+1))
    print(str(a1)+str(a2+2))
    print(str(a1)+str(a2+3))
    print(str(a1)+str(a2+4))
    line = f.readline()
f.close()
```

Comment: Для того, что-бы что-то заносилось в файл, его туда надо писать. У вас нет ни одной команды записи. (write).  Почитайте про ввод-вывод на python хоть что-нибудь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Открывать файлы лучше с помощью конструкции `with open`. Потому что так они автоматически закроются.
2. Не нужно писать результат в тот же файл - лучше заведеите новый. В моем случае `result.txt`
3. Вместо конкатинации строк через `+`, можно использовать `f-строку`

```py
with open('test.txt') as file:
    lines = file.read().splitlines()

with open('result.txt', 'a') as file:
    for line in lines:
        a1 = line[:-2]
        a2 = int(line[-3:-1])
        file.write(f'{a1}{a2+1}\n')
        file.write(f'{a1}{a2+2}\n')
        file.write(f'{a1}{a2+2}\n')
        file.write(f'{a1}{a2+2}\n')
```

Comment: file.write(f'{a1}{a2+1}\n')  
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @МишаХитч а у вас точно версия 3.6? Такой вариант записи строк появился как раз с 3.6. Раньше так нельзя было. Ну, если не рабоатет, попробуйте заменить на обычную конкатинацию, как у вас было до того или сделайте это с помощью метода format - `'{}{}\n'.format(a1, a2+1)`

Comment: 3.8.2 shell пишет сверху

Comment: а если я хочу всё-таки вписывать в старый файл?.... можете написать в ответ вторую версию для этого...?

Comment: @МишаХитч  Ну замените result.txt на test.txt да и все

Comment: в python плагине для notepad++ не поддерживается видимо file.write.... как-то по другому можно записать результат в файл?, потому что PRINT даёт результат в консоль....

Comment: format ничего не выводит

Comment: @МишаХитч код из ответа работает. Я проверял. Вы пытаетесь делать что-то странное, но экстрасенсы уехали в отпуск.

Comment: я совсем новый в этом деле... пытаюсь как могу..... где должен лежать файл test.txt  ?? (p.s. я пытался прописывать путь к файлу... но ничего не работало)

Comment: и куда сохраняется result ?